# Help me find this dark anime/cartoon movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

The film I'm looking for is about 2 boys living at different homes and and are going into training to be space war fighters.

One character evolved telekinetic power and started a  new  training and became leader of this group. He had a cape that  was pink on  the inside.
This character ended up back on Earth to repopulate mankind in the  old way of intercourse instead of being made in a test tube

Second character was in the same training as the first and called something like soldier blue and had a super computer called "mom," I think.

A specific scene is the 2 boys fighting in a school canteen.

The movie end scene is back on Earth and you see the first character being a farmer.
I think it is a late '70s or early '80s movie. Dark feeling over the whole movie.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *[Toward the Terra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toward_the_Terra)*?

> The story takes place in the distant future sometime after the 31st millennium where humanity exists under the rule of the political order controlled by supercomputers known as Superior Dominance and the carefully selected humans known as the Members Elite. Centuries before the story begins, the human race came to the conclusion that war and pollution rendered life on Earth unsustainable. Using warp travel the decision was made to leave a supercomputer Artificial Intelligence and caretaker humans behind and colonize distant stars.
>
> Under the rule of Superior Dominance all humans are born in vitro and given to carefully selected parents. At the age of 14, all children are put through brainwashing where their memories are wiped by Superior Dominance and overwritten to produce functional adults. A race of advanced humans with psionic abilities called Mu (pronounced myuu, μ) has evolved, and the supercomputers that control Superior Dominance make every effort to exterminate them. **Led by Soldier Blue and then Soldier Shin**, the Mu make every effort to locate and rescue as many Mu children as possible before the children are discovered and eliminated. The Mu have only one wish, to return to what they see as their promised land, Terra.